# How do I remove specific characters from a data frame

Tags: r

I have a raw data frame that i am cleaning up.

there's a column with thousands of rows that look like : `c("round", "square", "triangle")`

I would like the end result for each row to look like : `round, square, triangle`

help?

```
dput(ItemisedOrders[1:10, "Products", drop = FALSE])

structure(list(Products = list("Meatlovers Pizza", c("Supreme Pizza", 
"BBQ Chicken Pizza"), c("Seafood Pizza", "Vegetarian Pizza"), 
    c("Margherita Pizza", "Supreme Pizza", "Meatlovers Pizza"
    ), c("BBQ Chicken Pizza", "Hawaiian Pizza", "Meatlovers Pizza"
    ), c("Hawaiian Pizza", "Supreme Pizza"), c("Hawaiian Pizza", 
    "Pepperoni Pizza"), c("Seafood Pizza", "BBQ Chicken Pizza", 
    "Vegetarian Pizza", "Hawaiian Pizza"), "Pepperoni Pizza", 
    c("Margherita Pizza", "Supreme Pizza"))), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share reproducible example of your dataframe using dput(dataframe_name)

Comment: A reproducible example of **a small subset** is best. `dput(your_data_frame[1:10, "weird_column", drop = FALSE])` would be good for the first 10 rows of that weird column (put in the actual data frame name and column name, of course). Chose different rows if the first 10 don't show the problem well.

Comment: It sounds like there may be a problem with your data *import* or *creation*, since having strings resembling R expressions is certainly not normal. Perhaps you can share how you created this frame?

Comment: @GregorThomas  Kindly see below

structure(list(Products = list("Meatlovers Pizza", c("Supreme Pizza", 
"BBQ Chicken Pizza"), c("Seafood Pizza", "Vegetarian Pizza"), 
    c("Margherita Pizza", "Supreme Pizza", "Meatlovers Pizza"
    ), c("BBQ Chicken Pizza", "Hawaiian Pizza", "Meatlovers Pizza"
    ), c("Hawaiian Pizza", "Supreme Pizza"), c("Hawaiian Pizza", 
    "Pepperoni Pizza"), c("Seafood Pizza", "BBQ Chicken Pizza", 
    "Vegetarian Pizza", "Hawaiian Pizza"), "Pepperoni Pizza", 
    c("Margherita Pizza", "Supreme Pizza"))), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @r2evans, yeah it's strange that the data resembles that of a vector but when i pass through commands for a vector it doesn't respond. And as much as i try to manipulate the data i still am left with c(...

I have been able to use the lapply function to remove the quotation marks " - > 
lapply(df, gsub, pattern='"', replacement='')
but it doesn't work for other characters such as c&(

Also, I didn't create the data frame. I am just tasked with cleaning it.

Comment: Would you please edit the `dput` output into your question? That will make it easy to find for anybody. Looks like you've got a `list` column, so we can certainly help you with this issue, but I agree with r2evans - at some point you load this data into R (maybe you connect to a database, read a file, ...?), and there might be a way to fix the issue then. If you post the code that you use to load the data into your R session, we might be able to help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the `dput` - it looks like you have a `list` column - each row is a vector! We can use `sapply` to apply a function to each row, and luckily the `toString` function does what you want. Calling your data `df`:

```
df$Products = sapply(df$Products, toString)
df
# 1                                                    Meatlovers Pizza
# 2                                    Supreme Pizza, BBQ Chicken Pizza
# 3                                     Seafood Pizza, Vegetarian Pizza
# 4                   Margherita Pizza, Supreme Pizza, Meatlovers Pizza
# 5                 BBQ Chicken Pizza, Hawaiian Pizza, Meatlovers Pizza
# 6                                       Hawaiian Pizza, Supreme Pizza
# 7                                     Hawaiian Pizza, Pepperoni Pizza
# 8  Seafood Pizza, BBQ Chicken Pizza, Vegetarian Pizza, Hawaiian Pizza
# 9                                                     Pepperoni Pizza
# 10                                    Margherita Pizza, Supreme Pizza
```

Comment: oh excellent. Thank you so much! - I was thinking it wasn't a vector because it wasn't responding to my commands. but i'm a novice - I learn something new everyday. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, it's not a vector - it's a list of vectors. That's why we need the `sapply`.

Comment: ^^ yes you are totally correct. This is probably why I was unsure how to proceed. I've never worked with a list of vectors before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but if its in a dataframe and you just want to remove the quotation marks you could try:

`your_data$coulmn_name <- gsub(""", "", your_data$coulmn_name)`

Where what ever is inside the first "" is what gets replaced and whatever is in the second "" is what replaces it, by keeping them closed nothing will replace it

EDIT

I hadn't actually tried running it, I think because there symbols r uses as operators they are a bit more tricky. I've got it to work with:

```
df$Products <- gsub("\"", "", df$Products)
df$Products <- gsub("c", "", df$Products)
df$Products <- gsub("[()]", "", df$Products)
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Yes its in a data frame, but the Raw data wasn't gathered in R. so the column that has the data with c("Supreme Pizza", "BBQ Chicken Pizza") doesn't respond as a vector would. I have been able to remove the quotation marks using lapply  -> lapply(df, gsub, pattern='"', replacement=''). and it can only remove the "" quotation marks not the c&( 

I have also just attempted your solution  :
Orders$Products <- gsub("c("c(", "", Orders$Products)

it has returned :
invalid regular expression 'c(', reason 'Missing ')''

Comment: This is the wrong approach, as OP's `dput` show that it's a `list` column, not a character vector that needs editing. If it were a character vector in need of `gsub`bing, you'd want to be careful with that `"c"`, I think `"^c"` would be better as one would only want to get rid of it at the start of the string

Comment: Ah good point. I can't say I've ever worked with list columns.